# image segmentation without labeling

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, label, image-segmentation

Is there any image segmentation model for segmenting images without putting labels for segmented parts (and bounding boxes)? I need to segment my image even for not-trained objects, so I guess I should use a model that does not have specific labels for segmenting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about DL theory and/or methodology - please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/deep-learning/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for unsupervised image segmentation?

https://github.com/kanezaki/pytorch-unsupervised-segmentation
https://github.com/Mirsadeghi/Awesome-Unsupervised-Segmentation

include some potential solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried the unsupervised model. it seems that it is not really accurate, I am looking for a model that is trained to segment the object based on their counter and shape, not label.

Comment: @Sahars: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by counter, but there are a couple more alternatives you can try: 1). Supervised image segmentation, albeit with pre-trained models, e.g., https://github.com/divamgupta/image-segmentation-keras or 2). classical image segmentation algorithms. There are lots of other implementations that you can try e.g., https://github.com/Borda/pyImSegm - would recommend that you do a thorough search and/or specify the exact problem you are trying to solve